# Iterating through a List and create another list

Tags: apex, list, array

I'm trying to iterate through a list and create multiple records with it but I am not able to.
The list is created and filled with the changeHandler event:

```
if(event.target.name==='psProduct'){
            this.psRecList[event.target.accessKey].Schedule__c = this.scheduleValue;
            this.psRecList[event.target.accessKey].Product__c = event.target.value;
        }
        else if(event.target.name==='psDescription'){
            this.psRecList[event.target.accessKey].Description__c = event.target.value;
        }
        else if(event.target.name==='psJan'){
            this.psRecList[event.target.accessKey].Jan__c = event.target.value;
        }
        else if(event.target.name==='psFeb'){
            this.psRecList[event.target.accessKey].Feb__c = event.target.value;
        }
        else if(event.target.name==='psMar'){
            this.psRecList[event.target.accessKey].Mar__c = event.target.value;
        }
```

In my controller, I create the record with insert psList and it works well but the goal is to create multiple record and not only one with all the fields.
this is the psList data abc | def | 22 | 33 | ... I wan to create a abc | def | 22, a abc | def | 33 records and so on.
I wanted to use a loop as below but I can't make it work...

```
@AuraEnabled
    public static List<scheduleTable__c> createPSs(List<scheduleTable__c> psList){
        
       List<scheduleTable__c> arraySC = new List<scheduleTable__c>();

        for(Integer i = 3; i < psList.size(); i++){
            arraySC.add(psList[0]);
            arraySC.add(psList[1]);
            arraySC.add(psList[2]);
            arraySC.add(psList[i]);
            insert arraySC;
        }

        //insert psList;
        //return psList;
        system.debug(arraySC);
        return arraySC;
    }
```

The array psList is not empty but the arraySC is...
Thanks!

Comment: How many elements are in psList? If you have 3 elements in there, the for-loop will not execute. And if there were, you would be adding elements 0-2 multiple times.

Comment: it can be many elements and yes, it is intended to have 0-2 many times. result should be:
abc | def | 222
abc | def | 333...